# PHP readfile always return "Error of network"

Tags: php, download, readfile

I want to download images from the URL with `readfile()` function but when finishing the download, returns:

> Error: Error of network

This my code:

```
<?php

    $file = $_REQUEST['file'];
    $file_extension = end(explode('.', $file));
    $file_name = end(explode('/', $file));
    $filepath = str_replace('https://example.org/', '', $file);

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filepath).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
    flush(); // Flush system output buffer
    readfile($filepath);
    exit;
```

I tried in different ways (`fread()`, `fopen()`, ...), but the result is the same.

Comment: Try to echo those headers and filepath, if everything is ok ...

Comment: Why are you using file functions instead of something meant for network requests like cURL?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to behave as expected, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php for the following text:

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen
>   wrappers have been enabled. See fopen() for more details on how to
>   specify the filename. See the Supported Protocols and Wrappers for
>   links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have,
>   notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they
>   may provide.

According to the documentation you'll have to enable fopen wrappers in order for these (file oriented) API's to work over a network